# How can I get direction or link of file in computer

Tags: c++, windows, file

I want to import an `.obj` file in my Engine or open some files. To do that I write a link or direction of that file in my computer. Like this

```
file.open("../Engine/data/model.obj");
```

But I don't want to write a link every time. In most application if you want to import or open a file you click on `import` or `open` and it opens a window where you search that file in your computer and click `open`.
Here is a picture to see what I talking am about.

[image]

How it is done? How can I write a C++ program to get link of a file like here? Does Windows have an API for something like this?

Comment: Side note: please, please, please do not make your game Windows exclusive.

Comment: The question is also not very clear. What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to present the user with a file choosing dialogue, you should check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145910/cross-platform-native-open-save-file-dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following: (if I understand you correctly)

-E.g get the path of your applications root folder

```
std::string rootDir = "";

char buffer[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
std::string::size_type pos = std::string(buffer).find_last_of("\\/");
std::string pathstr = std::string(buffer).substr(0,pos);
rootDir = pathstr.c_str(); // e.g = "C:\xx\Desktop\abc"
```

then use it like:

```
file.Open(path + "\\data\\Model.obj");
```

---

or, so you can do it more simplier for you:

```
File fileOpen(std::string filePath)
{
    return file.Open(path + filePath);
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to know how to make a FileDialog, google it please.. There are soo much sources.